# Horizontal ProgressBar: Toggling between determinate and indeterminate

Tags: android, progress-bar, toggle, seekbar

I'm trying to toggle a `SeekBar` between the the two modes to display the state of streaming media.

I've established that the correct graphics show when defining the `android:indeterminate` tag in XML:

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:progressDrawable="@android:drawable/progress_horizontal"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@android:drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal"
    android:indeterminateBehavior="cycle"
    android:indeterminateOnly="false"
    android:progress="33"
    android:secondaryProgress="66"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"></SeekBar>
```

[image: example]

The trouble is, when trying to switch by calling `setIndeterminate(true)`, the drawables don't appear to change properly. In the case of indeterminate->determinate, the animation stops, and from determinate->indeterminate, nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SeekBar onSizeChanged() initializes only the current selected background drawable, and it is called once when the SeekBar is initialized.
So a fix might be:

```
public class CorrectedSeekBar extends SeekBar {

    public CorrectedSeekBar(Context context) {
         super(context);
    }

    public CorrectedSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
         super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CorrectedSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        boolean current = isIndeterminate();
        setIndeterminate(!current);
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        setIndeterminate(current);
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

}
```

And in the layout xml use `<yourpackage.CorrectedSeekBar ...`

This doesnt look nice, other workarounds might be possible but I think this is the main problem (bug?).

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem and I solved it by calling postInvalidate() to force the view refresh.
I'm on Android 2.3.4.

```
// Configure the SeekBar
seekBar.setIndeterminate(true);
seekBar.postInvalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well instead setting the pd to indeterminate just switch its background. if you want drawable animations then i suggest to look into the TransitionDrawable here: [TransitionDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html). so the use of it is to actually add 2 different drawables and animate their transition. i think that should work for your case. but i don't have experience doing something like this on a progress dialog so i cant really tell.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. That's not what I'm going for; it seems like a messy hack. Setting the background wouldn't work, as the background is the black area in the picture above. Replacing the idle state drawable of the bar itself with a transition drawable *might* work, but then I've have to set the primary and secondary progresses to 0, then trigger the transition drawable. It's needlessly complicated - if I had to do that, I might as well just use two seekbars, and a viewflipper.

Comment: well what i mean with background is actually changing the progress bar style, yes primary and secondary progress drawables. you can just set those dinamically in runtime depending on what you need, and as for the transition drawable i think is a better way to go than a viewflipper, and making such drawable resource will require not more than 10 lines of code so i dont think that is really complicated. its certanly easier than 2 progress bar and keeping track of those.

Comment: Yeah, just tried it and it doesn't work. The progressdrawable is actually a layer-list, so when it's wrapped in a transition drawable, the sub-drawables don't seem to be exposed to the progressbar. You end up only seing the default drawable. For the same reason, the indeterminate drawable doesn't animate either.

Comment: Well as i said i haven't tried it myself but i am curious if you find another solution that will work.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is actually very simple, the same trick you have to use to start an animated drawable. This issue only seems to affect Android 2.3 (maybe also older versions of Android).

whenever you want to set:

```
progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
```

use this part of code instead:

```
this.progressBar.post(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    }
});
```